# how to change div content by time of the day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, dynamic-content

I want to be able to change the content of a certain div according to the time of the user. 
For example, if it's 5am, certain content would show. If it's 6am, another content shows.

```
John Doe 8am-4pm (changes to that name when its 8am-4pm)
John Doe 5pm-6pm (changes to that name when its 5pm-6pm)
John Doe 7pm-8pm (changes to that name when its 7pm-8pm)
```

I was using http://www.venivortex.com/open-source/jquery-rotator.php but it doesn't work. Anyone know of something similar?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you expand on what "doesn't work" about the rotator you're using?

Comment: Can you user server side code?

Comment: In that it changes by the hour switch_every: "hour" and also it doesn't show any content. Here is my attempt: http://wsul.com/new_build/rotator.html

Comment: js/jquery.rotator.0.1.js is not found. Try pointing to the right file?

Comment: That is true. I am no longer using this sample as it only works by day, I needed it by the hour, which the answers helped! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jruddell/SfXFF/12/) should be a good start for you:

```
$(function(){

    $('#timeperiod1').mood({
        range: [1, 7] // hours
    });
    $('#timeperiod2').mood({
        range: [7, 12] // hours
    });
    $('#timeperiod3').mood({
        range: [12, 24]  // hours
    });
});

// the jquery plugin
// TODO: add end of day re init
//       add min/sec along with hours
$.fn.mood = (function(){
    var Mood = function(el, opts){
        this.el = $(el);

        this.range = { bottom: opts.range[0]*1, top: opts.range[1]*1 };
        this.init();
    };
    Mood.prototype = {
        init: function(){
            this.initTime = this.checkTime(); // 1, 0, -1

            this.initTime == 0 ? this.show() : this.hide();
            this.start();
        },
        start: function(){
            var t = new Date(), 
                showDate = new Date(t), 
                hideDate = new Date(t), 
                h = t.getHours(), hide = false, show = false;

            if(this.initTime < 0) {// time has not yet come
                showDate.setHours(this.range.bottom);
                showDate.setMinutes(0);
                show = true;

            }
            if(this.initTime <= 0){
                hideDate.setHours(this.range.top);
                hideDate.setMinutes(0);
                hide = true;
            }
            debugger;
            show && setTimeout($.proxy(this.show, this), Math.ceil(showDate.getTime()-t.getTime()));
            hide && setTimeout($.proxy(this.hide, this), Math.ceil(hideDate.getTime()-t.getTime()));
        },

        checkTime: function(){
            var t = new Date(), h = t.getHours();
            if(h >= this.range.bottom && h <= this.range.top)
                return 0;
            if(h < this.range.bottom)
                return -1;  
            if(h > this.range.top)
                return 1;  
        },
        show: function(){
            this.el.show('slow');
        },
        hide: function(){
            this.el.hide('slow');
        }

    };

    return function(opts){
        return this.data('rotateMood', new Mood(this, opts));    
    };
})();
```

Comment: I like that one, Josiah! Thank you. I will try it.

Comment: Josiah, I just tried it. For some reason when I change the hour numbers, it shows two at a time. Is there a reason for that? (timeperiod2 and timeperiod3)

Comment: @Francheska - What is the time range? (You can save the fiddle and paste the link in the comments so i can look)

Comment: @Francheska - i updated it again, simplified a few things. Also note I had the demo wrong. The ranges are exclusive. so `range[0] = [1, 6]`, `range[1] = [6, 12]`, etc. difference is the next range stats with the same hour as the previous end. Glad I could help! Remember to accept one of the solutions.

Answer (score 4):

very tersely

```
//initialize date object
var d = new Date();
var currentHour = d.getHours(); //note 0-23

if (currentHour < 6) 
 { 
     $('div').append('Before 6am');
  }
else if (currentHour == 7)
{
   $('div').append('7am');
}
else {
   $('div').append('Time Now' + d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes()); 
  }
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/9dUJ6/

expand with else if

> getDate()   Returns the day of the
>   month (from 1-31)
>       getDay()    Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)
>       getFullYear()   Returns the year (four digits)
>       getHours()  Returns the hour (from 0-23)
>       getMilliseconds()   Returns the milliseconds (from 0-999)
>       getMinutes()    Returns the minutes (from 0-59)
>       getMonth()  Returns the month (from 0-11)
>       getSeconds()    Returns the seconds (from 0-59)
>       getTime()   Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1,
>   1970
>       getTimezoneOffset() Returns the time difference between GMT and local
>   time, in minutes
>       getUTCDate()    Returns the day of the month, according to universal time
>   (from 1-31)
>       getUTCDay() Returns the day of the week, according to universal time
>   (from 0-6)
>       getUTCFullYear()    Returns the year, according to universal time
>   (four digits)
>       getUTCHours()   Returns the hour, according to universal time (from
>   0-23)
>       getUTCMilliseconds()    Returns the milliseconds, according to
>   universal time (from 0-999)
>       getUTCMinutes() Returns the minutes, according to universal time
>   (from 0-59)
>       getUTCMonth()   Returns the month, according to universal time (from
>   0-11)
>       getUTCSeconds() Returns the seconds, according to universal time
>   (from 0-59)
>       getYear()   Deprecated. Use the getFullYear() method instead
>       parse() Parses a date string and returns the number of milliseconds
>   since midnight of January 1, 1970
>       setDate()   Sets the day of the month (from 1-31)
>       setFullYear()   Sets the year (four digits)
>       setHours()  Sets the hour (from 0-23)
>       setMilliseconds()   Sets the milliseconds (from 0-999)
>       setMinutes()    Set the minutes (from 0-59)
>       setMonth()  Sets the month (from 0-11)
>       setSeconds()    Sets the seconds (from 0-59)
>       setTime()   Sets a date and time by adding or subtracting a specified
>   number of milliseconds to/from
>   midnight January 1, 1970
>       setUTCDate()    Sets the day of the month, according to universal time
>   (from 1-31)
>       setUTCFullYear()    Sets the year, according to universal time (four
>   digits)
>       setUTCHours()   Sets the hour, according to universal time (from
>   0-23)
>       setUTCMilliseconds()    Sets the milliseconds, according to universal
>   time (from 0-999)
>       setUTCMinutes() Set the minutes, according to universal time (from
>   0-59)
>       setUTCMonth()   Sets the month, according to universal time (from
>   0-11)
>       setUTCSeconds() Set the seconds, according to universal time (from
>   0-59)
>       setYear()   Deprecated. Use the setFullYear() method instead
>       toDateString()  Converts the date portion of a Date object into a
>   readable string
>       toGMTString()   Deprecated. Use the toUTCString() method instead
>       toLocaleDateString()    Returns the date portion of a Date object as a
>   string, using locale conventions
>       toLocaleTimeString()    Returns the time portion of a Date object as a
>   string, using locale conventions
>       toLocaleString()    Converts a Date object to a string, using locale
>   conventions
>       toString()  Converts a Date object to a string
>       toTimeString()  Converts the time portion of a Date object to a
>   string
>       toUTCString()   Converts a Date object to a string, according to
>   universal time
>       UTC()   Returns the number of milliseconds in a date string since
>   midnight of January 1, 1970, according
>   to universal time
>       valueOf()   Returns the primitive value of a Date objecti

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date provides and overview of the date object

so too does w3schools
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp